# flot graph not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have a flot jquery graph but the lines are not displaying. It just displays the graph with x and yaxis but not data lines.

{!formatteddata1} gets a string with the series values from salesforce

The alert gives these values

```
[1294041600000,14.00],[1294041600000,14.50],[1294041600000,15.00],[1293955200000,12.00]
```

Below is the code to generate the graph.

```
j$('#loadgraph').click(function() {
    var d1=[];
    d1='{!formatteddata1}';
    alert(d1);


j$.plot(j$("#placeholder"),[d1],{
        xaxis: 
        { mode: "time", 
            min: (new Date("2010/11/01")).getTime(),
            max: (new Date("2011/02/01")).getTime()
            }
 ,yaxis: {
              min:0, max: 24,  tickSize: 5 
            }

 });
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey mate,
The `d1` shouldn't be a `String`, you're declaring it as an array but you're pushing the value with single quotes changing it to string. Change this:

```
var d1=[];
d1='{!formatteddata1}';
```

to this:

```
var d1=[{!formatteddata1}];
```

Cheers

G.

Comment: Thanks a ton... It was so simple